# Remove file from my pr without removing it form target branch?

Tags: git

I accidentally added committed a file into my pull request. I want that file to be the same as in the target branch and next push I want that file out of my pr. I tried **git rm** but looks like it will delete that file from target branch when merged. so what is my way out?

Comment: So do you want the file to be the same as the target, or do you want that file entirely removed?  Which one is it?

Comment: if I wanted it to be removed then I would have used git rm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing to know: PRs don't "contain" files, so the notion "remove file from my PR" is nonsense. A PR is just a branch that you intend to merge into another branch. Branches don't contain files either; they contain commits. Commits *do* contain files, in a sense, but not in an individual way; every commit contains *all* your files.

All *you* probably mean is that you don't like the fact that the web interface is displaying a diff that tells you that this branch is threatening to make a change in this file that you dislike.

So why not just push a commit that makes the file look the same as the target branch (the branch you intend to merge into)?

The pull request web interface then won't show that file as one of the files changed, because its diff with the target branch will be empty. And the merge won't have any effect on the file in the target branch. That seems to be the goal.

A good way to make this happen is (working on the pull request branch):

```
git show targetBranch:myFile > myFile
git add myFile
git commit -m 'fixed myFile'
git push
```

Comment: If the target branch contained changes not in your branch, they will now be in your branch too. This can be confusing (and depending on your workflow/policies not the right thing to do). Better to get the file's contents from the merge base. And if you don't like typing the file name 3 times, use `git checkout targetBranch -- myFile` instead of the first two commands ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new commit on top of your pr branch with the reverted file changes:

```
git checkout targetBranch -- file
git commit -m 'Revert file changes'
git push
```

Or you can always amend your commit and force push too if you don't want an extra commit.

```
git checkout targetBranch -- file
git commit --amend --no-edit 
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

A branch points to the tip of a series of commits. Each commit points to a *tree* of *blobs* or nested trees. Trees describe directories, blobs describe file contents. Each blob contains the *full* file content. Consequently, each commit describes a *full snapshot* of your repository at any point in time.

When branching and merging branches (e.g. accepting a GitHub PR), only the *difference* between both tip/head commits of the branches is merged into the target branch.

---

I assume that you want to restore this one file to its initial version of the target branch, before you started your branch. You can do this by running `checkout`/`restore` and providing the merge-base commit and the path to the file. Either one should work:

```
git checkout "$(git merge-base target-branch your-branch)" -- path/to/file
git restore --source="$(git merge-base target-branch your-branch)" -- path/to/file
```

After running one of above's command you will notice "new" changes about to be committed in your staging area. These changes are the inverse of your accidental changes and will restore the file to its initial state. Run `git commit` to persist this new snapshot on top of your current branch.

---

**Advanced**: Afterwards, you might want to run `git rebase` to squash this commit into the "faulty" commit. That way, the branch's history will never mention a change to this file at all—as if it has never changed at all.